# how to set height of uilabel equal to uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a grouped style Tableview which have uilabels in Tableviewcell. Now i want to set height of uilabels equal to height of cell how can i do ths???

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

// here i want to make height of label equal to height of cell
UILabel *category = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95,1,140,25)];
category.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
category.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
[category setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell addSubview:category];
}
```

Comment: i have already tried it before asking this question.  cell.bounds.size.height retuning height = 320.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath add; this will return current height set for your tableview:

```
CGFloat currentCellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, customWidth, currentCellHeight)];
```

Comment: tableView.rowHeight is giving me height equal to 44; but i have set cells height in heightForRowAtIndexPath equal to 30. how gan i get exact same ?

Comment: i got no visible interface declares heightForRowAtIndexPath .

Answer (score 1):

Get default cell height

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];



UILabel *category = [[UILabel alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.width)];
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use following to find height in

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


CGSize textSize = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",label.text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
return textSize.height; //height for cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your cell's height, just do the following:

```
category.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,cell.bounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

  // Look at this 

 UILabel *category = [[UILabel alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.bounds.size.width,cell.bounds.size.height)];


    category.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
    category.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [category setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell addSubview:category];
    }
```

use this code...

Comment: i have already tried it before asking this question.  cell.bounds.size.height retuning height = 320.

Comment: same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two things you can do; first try reading [this link from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) and review your approach. If you only need a label, why not use the cells `textLabel` and customize its appearance?

If you really want to use the label approach then consider adding it to the contentView instead of the cell. You can also try to get the bounds of this property, instead of the c

```
UILabel *category = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:category];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already used textLabel thats what i have to use uilabel. another thing this answer also just giving me height= 44.

Comment: I still think you should use the contentview to add your subviews. 44 is the default height unless you override heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I wish i could. And i have already overrided heightForRowAtIndexPath method. Though i got 44.

Comment: This is very weird. I have something like this -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 55;
} and when I NSLog the cell.contentView.bounds.height it prints 55.

Answer (score 0):

// try this code

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95,1,140,cell.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the cell bounds to label's frame,like below.

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];